# How to add image using ::before pseudo elemnent

Tags: html, css, image, pseudo-element

I am working on a new project and I am new to `::before` & `::after` pseudo elements in CSS3.

I have the following Figma design:

[image]

I have tried to create such a design by myself but got this output:

[image]

Here, I am facing two issues:

1. I don't know why the image is blur here.
2. There's a `div` at last with some gradient border.

I'm not able to create it using the `::after` pseudo-element. I tried to fix both of these issues but was not able to.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

```css
.middle-div {
  width: 427.23px;
  height: 528.56px;
  background: rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.37);
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  filter: blur(9.5px);
  border-radius: 22px;
  transform: matrix(1, 0, -0.08, 1, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
}

.middle-div::before {
  content: "";
  width: 427.23px;
  height: 528.56px;
  background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/100");
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  filter: drop-shadow(24px 19px 32px rgba(0, 188, 197, 0.01));
  border-radius: 251px;
  transform: matrix(1, 0, -0.1, 1, 0, 0);
}

.middle-div::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  width: 427.23px;
  height: 528.56px;
  filter: drop-shadow(22px 23px 12px rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.25));
  border-radius: 22px;
  transform: matrix(1, 0, -0.08, 1, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class='cta-image-container'>
  <div class="image-main-div">
    <div class="middle-div"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your goal using pseudo elements? You can do it using a simple div.

Answer (score -1):

```
filter: blur(9.5px);
```

is applying the blur effect.